# How to shift the text in a label over a little in Tkinter/TTK?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have labels FirstName, LastName, and License.
In my program, I wanted them justified to the left but I want them flush with the input boxes below them.  Currently, they are shifted a little further left.  I'm not having much luck moving them over just a tad.  Any suggestions?

```
import os
import pypyodbc
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


class Adder(ttk.Frame):
    """The adders gui and functions."""
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.init_gui()

    def on_help(self):
       answer = messagebox.showinfo("Stuff goes here.")

    def on_quit(self):
        """Exits program."""
        root.quit()


    def calculate(self):
        if len(self.lic_entry.get()) == 0:
            self.output['text'] = "Output will go here.\nThis is a test."



    def init_gui(self):
        """Builds GUI."""
        self.root.title('Verify')
        self.root.option_add('*tearOff', 'FALSE')

        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew') # this starts the entire form

        self.menubar = tkinter.Menu(self.root)

        self.menu_file = tkinter.Menu(self.menubar)
        self.menu_file.add_command(label='About', command=self.on_help)
        self.menu_file.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.on_quit)

        self.menu_edit = tkinter.Menu(self.menubar)

        self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=self.menu_file, label='File')
        # self.menubar.add_cascade(menu=self.menu_edit, label='Help')  # add other menu options

        self.root.config(menu=self.menubar)

        # Text Labels

        self.first = tkinter.Label(self, text='FirstName:')
        self.first.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='w')

        self.last = ttk.Label(self, text='LastName:')
        self.last.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='w')

        self.lic = ttk.Label(self, text='License:')
        self.lic.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky='w')

        # Input Boxes and Button

        self.first_entry = tkinter.Entry(self, width=28) # first input box
        self.first_entry.grid(sticky='e', column=0, row=2) 

        self.last_entry = tkinter.Entry(self, width=28) # second input box
        self.last_entry.grid(sticky='e', column=1, row=2) 

        self.lic_entry = tkinter.Entry(self, width=28) # third input box
        self.lic_entry.grid(sticky='e', column=2, row=2) 

        self.framespace = tkinter.Frame(self, height=10, width=600) # provides spacing between input boxes and button
        self.framespace.grid(column=0, row=4, columnspan=5)

        self.calc_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Search', command=self.calculate) # button
        self.calc_button.grid(column=0, row=5, columnspan=1, sticky='w')

        # Output frame for answers

        self.output = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, height=200, width=600, bg='#F7F7F7', text=' ', bd=0, labelanchor='n')
        self.output.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=5)

        for child in self.winfo_children():  # padx 10 adds horizontal padding on the out edge of window
            child.grid_configure(padx=0, pady=0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    Adder(root)
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False) # locks window from being resized
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the `padx` option in `grid`?

Comment: I have tried    self.first.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='w', padx='10')    and doesn't do anything.

Comment: Indeed, `padx=10` does nothing and I don't understand why. But when I make `Adder` inherit from `Tk` instead of `Frame`, then `padx` works as expected.

Comment: @j_4321: `padx=10` does nothing because the OP resets the `padx` and `pady` values and the end of `init_gui`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the explanation, I have just realized that I had removed the lines that reset the padding in my latest test.

Comment: Thanks all! It works.

Comment: `padx` works under the condition you remove `sticky=w`. I tried your code (`self.lic.grid(column=2, row=1, padx='10')`, `self.last.grid(column=1, row=1,padx='10')` and `self.first.grid(column=1, row=1,padx='10')`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `padding` option of the label to add padding inside the borders of the widget.

From the documentation:

> Specifies the amount of extra space to allocate for the widget. The padding is a list of up to four length specifications left top right bottom. If fewer than four elements are specified, bottom defaults to top, right defaults to left, and top defaults to left.

For example:

```
self.last = ttk.Label(..., padding=(2,0,0,0))
```

You could instead use `padx` when you call grid:

```
self.last.grid(..., padx=20)
```

However, the last won't seem to make a difference because later on in your code you reset the padx and pady values to zero. You will need to remove that code for `padx` to have an effect here.